# How to find the file address location for a file found in Spotlight

Tags: spotlight

The Spotlight application handily locates files for opening immediately. However, I want to know the found file's address from Spotlight in order to navigate to that location in Finder and move the file elsewhere.

In this specific example, I'm trying to find a `.tex` file to move to a more memorable location, but I don't remember where it is. Is there a way to find out the exact address location of the found file through Spotlight?

Comment: Hold cmd ⌘ when in spotlight, see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/386655/238687

Comment: @compuphys This could be the right answer, if not the poor implementation by Apple: Spotlight shows file preview. The path to the file is shown (when pressing `cmd ⌘`) in white letters. If the file has the white background, the path is completely invisible. So the answer by @k-dubs remains the only solution for this case. Good to know for other files though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Most-Recent Update:** At least as of MacOSX Ventura the file/directory location is displayed with holding `cmd` (as indicated by compuphys in this [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177355/how-to-find-the-file-address-location-for-a-file-found-in-spotlight/177357#comment526920_177355)), and hitting `Enter` will open a Finder window at that file's/directory's address location.

**First Update:** OS X Yosemite changed Spotlight quite a bit. Now the the file location is displayed in the lower right corner of Spotlight and `cmd`+`Enter` will open a finder tab with the searched file at the file's address.

**Original answer:**

From Spotlight: `Show All in Finder` -> `ctrl+click` the file -> `Show in Enclosing Folder` or select `Get Info`. Now you are at the file's location or have the files address (from `Get Info`) without opening the file.